# get the value from list in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hi everyone I am developing a client-side application using reactjs.
my question is if it's possible to get value using the column name

I have a list

```
var list = [{
      id: "1",
      FieldName: "FirstName",
      DisplayName: "First Name"
   },
   {
      id: "2",
      FieldName: "LastName",
      DisplayName: "Last Name"
   }
]
```

and object

```
 var item=  {
    id:"1",
    FirstName: "abc"
    LastName: "def"
    }
```

need to get the FirstName value using

```
  var value=list[0].FieldName;
  var result=item.value
```

my result as "abc"

it's possible to get the data.

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774142/compare-list-and-object-in-react

Comment: Please stop duplicating this question. It was closed for a reason.

Comment: You can simply do: `var result = item[value]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess something like this:

```
  var value=list[0].FieldName;
  var result=item[value]
```